# php error_log() not writing all errors to specified file

Tags: php, logging

I am using error_log() to write errors/logs to a specific file in my application.
I have seen a few occurrences where entries in logs are missing. Is this a known issue when we are doing excessive logging using error_log() function??

Answer (score 0):

1. Open php.ini
2. find `error log`.

If you want that errors should be logged in the same directory then,

```
error_log = error_log
```

else if you want it to be stored to a single file then,

```
error_log = /path/to/errorlog
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i think you did not understand my question. I am using error_log($message, 3, $filePath) to write logs to $filePath. This is working perfectly fine, except in a few cases when some expected logs are missing from file. These logs are important for my application so i want to know the reason when and why apache is unable to write to the file..